# How long will take from an average C# developer to an average Java developer?

Tags: c#, java

I know the ideas and features between C# and Java programming language is very similar. So  as a senior C# web developer(average) how long will it take to make it feel comfortable programming Java web applications? Will it just like from VB.net to C#?

Comment: It may be easier if you use libraries which emulate C# features. Check this one: github.com/nicholas22/jpropel, example:new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).distinct();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't be just like VB.NET to C#.

If you're an average .NET developer, it shouldn't take long at all before you're comfortable with the Syntax of Java. What is going to take a little longer is learning the different Web frameworks for Java Web Applications and how everything fits together.

That last part is going to take the majority of your time. How long exactly is anybody's guess.

Comment: "an average 'C#' .NET developer"

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is pretty easy.  I did the opposite transition in about 30 minutes.  The difficulty is learning the new framework and functions, which are much different.  I've been coding C# for 5+ years, and still don't know the entire framework.  I can see this being a problem with any new Java developer as well.

VB.Net->C# isn't a big deal, since they share the same framework functions.

Answer (score 3):

An experienced programmer will adapt to any programming language in a rather short time. The hard part is learning the frameworks and all the other bits and pieces of a new ecosytem.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, the differences are just a few, and you'll pick them up pretty quick if you've been doing C# for a long time.  I think the real adjustment is in the tools.  I'm a .Net programmer and I know I'm pretty spoiled by the Visual Studio, especially by Intellisence.  Eclipse is nice, but there is a little bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

As another who went from Java to C#, the most difficult part is adjusting to the IDE. The next most difficult thing is getting your head around which class in the one language is similar to the other.

You might also have trouble with the Java documentation, which is nowhere near as efficient or user-friendly as MSDN Help.